# meteor packages error "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Tags: meteor, leaflet

In my Meteor project I have included some leaflet packages (fuatsengul:­leaflet, bdunnette:­leaflet-draw). The map is drawn ok, but I am missing all the icons for the layer-controls and draw command buttons.
The browser console says:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:
"http://localhost:3000/packages/fuatsengul_leaflet/lib/images/layers.png".
```

Should I copy some png's to my /public folder by hand or is this supposed to be done by the packaging/build system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor isn't very good with 404s. What this means is that the URL is serving up a html file (Meteor's html file) even though it expects a png file.

This is how Meteor behaves instead of shelling out a 404.

To fix it you would have to modify the package to make the image files an asset, the alternative being to put it in your public folder such that it maps to `/packages/fuatsengul_leaflet/lib/images/layers.png`.

The best would be to modify the package.js and add in all the resources & submit a PR to the repo as it sounds like a bug in the package.